# why types/class unification majorly in python

Tags: python, class, types, new-style-class

I am quite an average programmer in python and i have not done very complex or any major application with python before ... I was reading new class styles and came across some very new things to me which i am understanding which is data types and classes unification

```
class defaultdict(dict):

    def __init__(self, default=None):
       dict.__init__(self)
       self.default = default

   def __getitem__(self, key):
       try:
           return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
       except KeyError:
           return self.default
```

but whats really getting me confused is why would they unify them? ... i really can't picture any reason making it of high importance .. i'll be glad if anybody can throw some light on this please Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by unify?

Comment: Like unit? ... like what are the benefits in creating a user defined data type? ..

Comment: @user3271483: What are the alternatives?

Comment: @Blender to do what, give me an example of a task i'll need user defined type ?

Comment: @user3271483: How would you define `defaultdict` without subclassing `dict`?

Comment: @Blender you can create a normal function and run the check as a boolean value to check if true return default else return d value

Comment: And how do you pass that function to code that's expecting a `dict`?

Comment: variable  = function(dict type) ... I think user defined types makes it more modular and understandable?

Comment: No: how do you pass your _function that does boolean checks before adding_ to a function that's wanting to add values to a `dict`?

Comment: variable = function(function(dict)) ... inner func returns either true or false outer function prints a default value lets say 0 or prints the value if present

Comment: @user3271483: But your function won't *behave* like a dictionary. When you subclass `dict`, the resulting class is a dictionary. You can use it in place of a regular dictionary because they have the same exposed methods. Your function is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary reason was to allow for built-in types to be subclassed in the same way user-created classes could be. Prior to new-style classes, to create a `dict`-like class, you needed to subclass from a specially designed `UserDict` class, or produce a custom class that provided the full `dict` protocol. Now, you can just do `class MySpecialDict(dict):` and override the methods you want to modify.

For the full rundown, see [PEP 252 - Making Types Look More Like Classes](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252/)

For an example, here's a `dict` subclass that logs modifications to it:

```
def log(msg):
    ...

class LoggingDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(LoggingDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        log('Updated: {}={}'.format(key, value))
```

Any instance of `LoggingDict` can be used wherever a regular `dict` is expected:

```
def add_value_to_dict(d, key, value):
    d[key] = value

logging_dict = LoggingDict()

add_value_to_dict(logging_dict, 'testkey', 'testvalue')
```

If you instead used a function instead of `LoggingDict`:

```
def log_value(d, key, value):
    log('Updated: {}={}'.format(key, value))

mydict = dict()
```

How would you pass `mydict` to `add_value_to_dict` and have it log the addition *without* having to make `add_value_to_dict` know about `log_value`?

Comment: How helpful as it been to you sir?

Comment: You don't need to pass it to add_value_to_dict .. Having done mydict = dict() ... Then log_value(mydict, 'testkey', 'testvalue')

Comment: Sorry, `log_value` shouldn't have done the addition, as it's only a logger. Question still stands: how can I log additions made to a `dict` by a function with a separate function?

Comment: why should the two functions not know each other? ... because you had answered it already in your code?

Comment: This isn't the place to get into the benefits of loose coupling. You asked for an answer and got it. If you don't need to use it, don't. Otherwise, you're descending into either pedantry or trolling.